# Create a big table with huge number of columns?

Tags: sql, database, data-mining

How can I create a table with 1000 row and at least 64000 columns. As I know, SQL database and Microsoft Excel suppot only 30000 and 16384 columns per table, respectively. How can I create such a table? Is there any solution? I want to use this table as an input for RapidMiner studio!

Comment: The maximum number of columns depends on the database.  64,000 columns would exceed the limits of most databases.

Comment: try to normalize it

Comment: What kind of data? Will you have to change / manipulate this monster? Is this kind of *de-normalized* DWH? Do you fill this once, or will you have to add / delete rows (if yes, how often?). Alltogether I'd say; Split this in several tables. If this must be done in one sinlge table (can't imagine why), you might use columns of type `XML` to store multiple values in one cell without violation `1.NF` directly...

Comment: Use appropriate tools (not excel, not SQL) and appropriate data models (you likely have sparse data).

Answer (score 0):

If you are determined to create this beast it would require a work around the column limit.

My suggestion would be 10x~6401 column tables with an ID/Key to link each row.

Join together the ten tables like so:

```
 select * from
 Table1
 join Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.ID
 join Table3 on Table1.ID = Table3.ID
```

etc etc

Whether this would work as a singular input for RapiMiner, I'm not sure